# Prints a sub-list where the sum of its elements is the same as the sum of all the elements of the original list

Tags: python, arrays, list, sublist

I have to write a Python code that when given a list of numbers, prints a sub-list where the sum of its elements is the same as the sum of all the elements of the original list. For example, considering the list of numbers [5, 6, 8, 6, 6, -12], the code should print the sub-list [5,6,8] since both original and sub-list elements have a sum value equal to 19; for the list

So far I’ve done:

```
list_1 = [5, 6, 8, 6, 6, -12]
sub_list = []

for i in list_1:
    sub_list.append(i)
    if sum(sub_list) == sum(list_1):
        sub_list.remove(i)
    for i in list_1:
        if sum(sub_list) == sum(list_1):
            sub_list.remove(i)

print(sub_list)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [these guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) on asking homework questions; we expect you to show proof that you've made a good faith effort to solve your question yourself before posting here.

Comment: I’ve answer your question

Comment: Can you explain what your algorithm is trying to do? For example, what is the purpose of the nested loop over `list_1`?

Comment: The algorithm you're looking for is "subsequence sum", by the way. E.g. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-all-subsequences-with-sum-equals-to-k/

Comment: My algorithm is trying to insert in the sub_list the numbers for which list_1 == sub_list.

Comment: Sure, but if you add to the sublist, and it does equal the total sum, you can break the loop and return immediately because that is a valid response. Why are you removing elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `lst` is your list of numbers then:

```
def get_sublist(lst):
    tot = sum(lst)
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(lst) + 1):
            sub_lst = lst[i:j]
            if sum(sub_lst) == tot:
                return sub_lst

sub_lst = get_sublist(lst)
```

This code generates every possible sublist, computes their sum and compares it with the sum of the entire list.

The complexity is not optimal, i.e. there are faster algorithms to solve this problem out there. For example, you don't need to compute the sum of the entire sublist every time you add a new element to it...